Associated bilinear form of a quadratic form
Consider $M_2(\mathbb C)$ be the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices equipped with the quadratic form $q(A) = - \det (A)$. Let $b$ be the associated bilinear form; to find it, we will use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.
The Cayley-Hamilton theorem says that $$\begin{align}
A^2 - \mathrm{tr}(A)A+ \det(A) = 0 &\implies \mathrm{tr}(A^2) - \mathrm{tr}(A)^2 +2 \det(A) = 0 \\
&\implies \det(A) = \frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{tr}(A)^2 - \mathrm{tr}(A^2)),
\end{align}$$ therefore the bilinear form is given by $$b(X, Y) = -\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{tr}(X) \, \mathrm{tr}(Y)  - \mathrm{tr}(XY)).$$ But in an article it is written that the associated bilinear form $b$ of $q$ is given by $$b(X, Y) = -\frac{1}{2}\det(Y) \, \mathrm{tr}(XY^{-1}).$$
Can anyone please help me to understand how both are the same?

what article would that be?

The computation is small enough that you might as well just compute $b(X, Y)$ in terms of the entries of $X$, $Y$. Also, notice that $\det Y \operatorname{tr} (X Y^{-1}) = \operatorname{tr} (X \operatorname{adj} Y)$, where $\operatorname{adj} Y$ denotes the adjugate of $Y$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

It's a little peculiar to define the bilinear form using $Y^{-1}$, since that quantity is not defined for all $Y$ in the vector space.

As Travis says in the comments, you can write $Y^{-1} = \frac{\text{adj}(Y)}{\det(Y)}$ where $\text{adj}(Y)$ is the adjugate, which gives
$$\det Y \text{tr}(XY^{-1}) = \text{tr}(X \text{ adj}(Y)).$$
Next, we can rearrange Cayley-Hamilton for $Y$ using $\det Y = Y \text{ adj}(Y)$ into the form
$$Y \text{ adj}(Y) = Y \text{ tr}(Y) - Y^2$$
and multiplying by $Y^{-1}$ then gives
$$\text{adj}(Y) = \text{tr}(Y) - Y.$$
(This works for $2 \times 2$ matrices only, of course.) So
$$\text{tr}(X \text{ adj}(Y)) = \text{tr}(X) \text{tr}(Y) - \text{tr}(XY)$$
as desired.
One way to interpret this calculation is that $M_2$ is a (split) quaternion algebra, with $\text{adj}$ playing the role of the quaternionic conjugate. It has the effect of switching the eigenvalues of a matrix (at least in the diagonalizable case). Similarly $\det$ plays the role of the quaternionic norm.
